# Thread.Sleep SpinWait.SpinUntil weird behavior

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the code bellow.

```
namespace SandBox
{
    static class Program
    {
        static ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        static void Main()
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer(worker, null, 0, 3000);
            while (true)
            {
                SpinWait.SpinUntil(IsEmpty); //???? freezes up here
                string snippet;
                while (!queue.TryDequeue(out snippet))
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                Console.WriteLine(snippet);
                Thread.Sleep(5000); //??????
            }
        }
        static void worker(object x)
        {
            queue.Enqueue("***___***___***");
        }

        static bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return queue.IsEmpty;
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't include `Thread.Sleep(5000);` it works as expected.
However, if I do, it outputs only one line and after that is just freezes up at the SpinUntil part and won't output any more lines. If I stop it and check if queue.IsEmpty true, the debugger says it is in fact false! (The worker does get called periodically, I checked with a breakpoint.) What's more, IsEmpty is getting called as well and is returning false.

What is happening?

Comment: Does it happen to hit `SpinUntil` once and then get stuck the 2nd time? You might be experiencing a deadlock. It should be easy enough to find out using your debugger.

Comment: @emsimpson92 A deadlock? `ConcurrentQueue` is thread safe. I am not using any shared resources beyond that. The above code produces the phenomena in it self.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to testing 'IsNotEmpty' instead of 'IsEmpty', SpinWait.SpinUntil run on you main thread, once you reach that line of code and the queue is not empty , it will never end waiting because there is no consumer anymore, your consumer is blocked by your wait. add Thread.Sleep(5000) doesn't help at all, it's a race condition/dead lock whatever you call it .

Comment: @LeY It is my understanding that `SpinUntil` spins as long as the delegate supplied to it returns true. So, it should come out of the spinning when isEmpty becomes false. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @Cerike the opposite of your understanding. Like it named , it will spins util IsEmpty return true.

Comment: @LeY Oh, wow. I totally believed the exact opposite... I have read its description in the documentation many times over, but it never even occurred to me that it would work the other way :(

Comment: @Cerike even better if you use BlockingCollection<T> instead of placing with lock/wait your self, BlockingCollection is make for this ProducerConsumer Pattern.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpinWait.SpinUntil` spins until the specified condition is satisfied. In you case the condition is `IsEmpty`, so it will spin *until* the queue is empty (or, if you will, *while* the queue is not empty).

Since with the wait you gave the thread time to put something into the queue, the spinner will keep spinning because it is in the thread that is supposed to empty the queue, but it can't because it is waiting on the spinner.

If it's easier to understand, `SpinUntil(IsEmpty)` is the same as saying `SpinWhile(IsNotEmpty)`.